# Корректно ли использовать СМО, для определния числа потоков, которые следует открыть, для обслуживания поступающих на сервер запросов?

Tags: многопоточность, сервер, математика, веб-сервер, потоки-данных

Корректно ли использовать CМО для расчета числа потоков, которые требуется открыть для обслуживания определенного числа потоков, в архитектуре использующей асинхронный ввод/вывод? Если это корректно, какое мат метод следует использовать?

Comment: Что такое СМО? Мне кажется логично просто добавлять потоки когда их перестанет хватать

Comment: А для асинхронных задачь нет смысла запускать больше потоков чем количество ядер

Comment: @eri, есть смысл, потому, что задача блокируется не только на ожидании CPU, но и на вводе/выводе